# Joomla PHP code

Tags: php, joomla

I'm new in using Joomla and i need your help please.

I'm newly working in a company. The company bought a web shop from other company and the web shop is live now.

One button in one of the pages is responsible to place an order and the action for this button is to send an email with all the data about the orders to my company.

Now my task is to develop an API which does the following:

- when clicking on that button the information should be handles in certain way and sent to other system which our company have and this system is used by my company to handle the different orders.

My problem is that i can't find the php page that contains the code which is creating these orders email in order to change it.
Is there is any tool or plugin which might help or do you have any idea how to handle this situation?

Hint: I'm not able to get any support from the company who programmed the web shop

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

It is very hard to tell you what to do when we don't even know which Joomla e-commerce extension you are using. Nevertheless, there are things that you can do to find out which file is doing the actual processing of the order.

However, before even doing that, you will need to define what "order processing" means. Is it when the order is saved to the database? Is it when the order is approved by the payment gateway?

In the first case, you will need to look up for code saving the data to the database (which is likely in the `models` folder of the extension - it might also be in the `controllers`), in the latter case, you will need to look up for the code processing the payment (which is likely in the `controllers` folder or the `helpers` folder).

Note that some "advanced" e-commerce extensions trigger events when an order is processed that you can use in a plugin in order to do what you want.